# PhoneGap Launch Image iOS Apple Store Submission

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect

As always the submission to `iTunesConnect` of my `PhoneGap` application is being rather troublesome. In particular is this new message I see pop up when I try to use `Application Loader`.

```
Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. - New iPhone apps and app updates 
submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch 
image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the 
&amp;lt;basename&amp;gt; portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images 
must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided 
within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images.
```

Per https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html I have created an image of 640 x 1136, named it "Launch_Image_640x1136-568h.png", and placed it in the www folder. Still, it gives me the error.

What's going on here? Hopefully this is something simple and easy to take care of, but I'm at my wit's end right now. Anyone have any information or solutions to this? Thanks.

****UPDATE****

I develop the app with `Aptana` 3 on `Windows` 8.1 and only use a mac for certificates, keys, p12 files, and uploading. I'm not using `PhoneGap` on a mac through xcode.

Comment: That may be the opinion of some, but you've got to admit that the solution and explanation for this thread is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I kept on and finally found the answer today here http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/iphone_5_optimization_requirement-on7f1 and here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml

In a nutshell the issue arose because `Apple`, in their never ending pursuit to make things difficult, now requires a "launch screen" image to be included in all apps. As a result, you now have to have, currently, 3 different sized launch screen images with a specific naming procedure on each. The solution that I found via the links above was to place the launch screen images in the root directory and add the following three lines to config.xml

```
<gap:splash src="Default.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="Default@2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
```

I'm not sure if the launch screen images are required to be in the root directory or not, but it works for me at the moment. Also, I'm not sure if the images have to begin with "Default", but I do know that the larger two images have to have "@2x" and "-568h@2x" on the end of the file name that's the same name as the smallest image.

For more information on "launch screens" see `Apple`'s documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be declared on the app. click on the Project file (the top most item in Xcode with the blue Xcode icon).  navigate to target / general settings launch image is one of the items.

Comment: My question was concerning PhoneGap, not Xcode.

Comment: That is what the error message is saying it x code will not really care if you are using phone gap or not.  .... Unless you are saying that the views tat phone gap is generating are fixed at the old size - 320x480.

Comment: I'm not using Xcode at any point though. I develop the app with Aptana on Windows and only use a mac for certificates, keys, p12 files, and uploading.

Comment: I double checked my phone gap project in Xcode - the mainviewcontroller.xib that phone gap generates is using 320x480 by defaultand may need to be adjusted to 320x568. This is easily remedied if you are using Xcode in the MAC, but could be hard to do with other tools, since the problem seems to be inherent with phone gap.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the information. I tried to edit the .nib (it wasn't .xib in my app) file, but with a normal text editor it didn't take. But hey, it was a long shot anyways. Anyways, I kept up my search and persevered and finally found the solution today. I'm creating an answer to this below with the information and link that I found in case others run into this issue using only PhoneGap and Windows without Xcode. Thanks again!