# iOS 7 App submission error about Launch Image

Tags: ios, ios7, deployment, app-store

> Here's somebody that had the same problem, but with PhoneGap: [PhoneGap Launch Image iOS Apple Store Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415681/phonegap-launch-image-ios-apple-store-submission)

I would like to to submit my app (target iOS7, iPhone only) and I'm using the .xcassets folder for
app icons and launch images.
When I click submit I get the following errors:

[image: First error]

and

[image: Second Error]

I checked the plist file of my archived application and it already has the necessary keys like 
UILaunchImage, UILaunchImageSize. See here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>14C323</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>AppIcon29x29</string>
                <string>AppIcon40x40</string>
                <string>AppIcon60x60</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleResourceSpecification</key>
    <string>ResourceRules.plist</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>iPhoneOS</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>11B506</string>
    <key>DTPlatformName</key>
    <string>iphoneos</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>7.0</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>11B506</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>iphoneos7.0</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0502</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>5A3005</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>7.0</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>7.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>LaunchImage-700</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 480}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>7.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>LaunchImage-700-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main_iPhone</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have no idea what is going wrong and why apple rejects it as the LaunchImage key apple is complaining about is here.

I'm already trying to solve this since several days, but can't figure it out.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
How could I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: In Xcode, go to the General tag for your project. Look under the "Launch Images" section. Does it show that you have set the iPhone "Retina 4-inch" image properly?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the Xcode project folder to check if your image is in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your device supports the new iPhone 5 height and make sure that you have the launch images for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is three kinds of images for iPhone,

1. Default.png (320X480)
2. Default@2x.png (640X960)
3. Default-568h@2x.png (640X1136)

If you name all your launch images as above and pull them into your project they will automatically be added as your launch images.